# Print labels and variable names with head

Tags: r

I am trying to use something like the `head` command in R, but also include the variable labels in the output to the console.

So far I have tested both `head()` and `dplyr::slice()` with data.frames and tibbles but nothing has the options to display labels as well as the column names.

Does anyone know if this is possible to do?

I'm trying to get something like this:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 21
SiteSeq   SiteName  SiteCode  SubjectSeq   SubjectId    EventSeq 
<Site No> <Name>    <Code>    <Patient No> <Patient ID> <Event No> 
2         Peter M~   PMC       1           PMC-001      1        
2         Peter M~   PMC       1           PMC-001      1        
2         Peter M~   PMC       1           PMC-001      1
```

Where the things in `<>` are the column labels.

I know the labels are viewable with `View()`, but I am just wondering if there is also a way to see them in the console. Thanks!

## Edit:

All variables are labelled using the `Hmisc::label()` command just after reading in the data. Eg, `label(data$variable1) <- "label1"`

Comment: How are you setting 'labels' on a data.frame?

Comment: Using `Hmisc::label(data$variable) <- "label"` on each of the variables

Comment: That's probably worth including in the question itself, as it is not a standard part of `data.frame` or even a `tibble`

Comment: Added, thanks for the advice

Comment: As a work-around you could create your own "head" function that would add the labels as the first row your data.frame and then print `head`

Comment: Thats a good idea, doesn't seem like there's an in-built way so I might give this a go :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the advice from @MRau here is a simple function that will print the labels along with the variable names when viewing in the console:

```
lhead <- function(df, n=7){  

  is.Date <- function(x){
    ifelse(inherits(x, c("POSIXt", "POSIXct", "Date")), TRUE, FALSE)
  }

  df2 <- df
  df2[sapply(df2, is.factor)] <- lapply(df2[sapply(df2, is.factor)], as.character)
  df2[sapply(df2, is.Date)] <- lapply(df2[sapply(df2, is.Date)], as.character)
  tmp <- rbind(label(df), df2)
  head(tmp, n)  
}
```

## Edit:

Had issues with dates so included extra date bit