# selecting column by name data and ignoring other column attributes such as "label" R

Tags: r

Any tips on selecting columns by just column name when other column attributes are present?

When using `dplyr::subset` and selecting from a `c(x, y, z)` sort of list, which should work when given exact column names, I am not able to get columns that also contain "*,label" attributes.

This is new to me, something I've not seen or dealt with before.

I can use `select` and `starts_with` but it's not limited enough as a character search and is getting other columns with similar character strings.

Doesn't work because of "label" attribute?

```
subset(NHSDA_2001_W, select = c("YEAR", "IRPINC3"))
```

works but yields far too many columns.

```
%>% select(starts_with("YEAR") | starts_with("IRPINC3"))
```

Is it possible to subset by name and ignore other column attributes?

Comment: If you provide your data, then it will be easier to troubleshoot. You can do `dput(head(NHSDA_2001_W))` in the console, then you can edit your question and paste the results. Then, we can have your dataframe structure and figure out the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little unclear what the issue is, as labels do not prevent you from selecting by column name. Note: I used a [different function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54082535/15293191) to print the labels in the console.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(labelled)

df <- iris
var_label(df) <- list(Petal.Length = "Length of petal", Petal.Width = "Width of Petal")

#  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width    Petal.Length    Petal.Width Species
#1                          Length of petal Width of Petal        
#2          5.1         3.5             1.4            0.2  setosa
#3          4.9           3             1.4            0.2  setosa
```

We can just use `select` as normal from `dplyr`:

```
df %>% 
  select(Petal.Length, Petal.Width) %>% 
  head()

  Petal.Length Petal.Width
1          1.4         0.2
2          1.4         0.2
3          1.3         0.2
4          1.5         0.2
5          1.4         0.2
6          1.7         0.4
```

Same for using `subset` (not part of `dplyr`):

```
subset(df, select = c(Petal.Length, Petal.Width))
```

Comment: i'm sorry i asked this stupidly. i messed up and did not notice that the case had changed between years, and that was the issue. the (*, "label") was something new and it through me off. is there anything tricky to be aware of when this kind of data row(?) is present?

Comment: @gered What kind of row in the data? I'm not sure I understand. It's easier to talk about with seeing the structure of your data (i.e., using `dput`).